# Ajax Security (i hope)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a browser game and im using a heavy amount of ajax instead of page refreshs. I'm using php and javascript. After alot of work i noticed that ajax isnt exactly secure. The threats im worried about is say someone wants to look up someones information on my SQL server they'd just need to key in right information to my .php file associated with my ajax calls. I was using GET style ajax calls which was a bad idea. Anyways after alot of research i have the following security measures in place. I switched to POST (which isnt really any more secure but its a minor deterent). I have a referred in place as well which again can be faked but again its another deterrent.

The final measure i have in place and is the focus of this question, when my website is loaded i have a 80 char hex key generated and saved in the session, and when im sending the ajax call i am also sending the challenge key in the form of

```
challenge= <?php $_SESSION["challenge"]; ?>
```

now when the ajax php file reads this it checks to see if the sent challenge matchs the session challenge. Now this by itself wouldnt do much because you can simply open up firebug and see what challenge is being sent easily. So what I'm having it do is once that challenge is used it generates a new one in the session.

So my question is how secure is this from where im standing it looks one could only see what the challenge key was after it was sent and then it renews and they couldnt see it again until it is sent, making it not possible to send a faked request from another source. So does anyone see any loop hole to this security method or have any addition thoughts or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer by 'meagar'.

I'd like to mention:

By passing around an identifier in Session, you're doing what the Session is already doing. There's usually a cookie with a unique identifier similar to the one you're generating, which is telling your application, essentially, who that person is. This is how PHP sessions work, in general.

What you would need to do, in this case, is check that for a given request - POST *or* GET - that the particular user (whose unique user ID, or similar, is stored in the Session) has permission to add/change/delete/whatever with that particular request.

So for a "search" request, you would only return results that User X has permission to view. That way, you don't worry about what they send - if the user doesn't have permission to do something, the system knows not to let them do it.

Hence "you should be authenticating all requests".

Someone feel free to add to this.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what i want to accmplish, could you give me any information on how i would authenicate someone using this unique identifier?

Comment: If you're working on a game, I'll assume you might have Users and Registration worked out. Beyond that, you're looking for something commonly referred to as "ACL". Essentially, users (or groups of users) are given sets of permissions for what they are allowed to do ("can add widget", "can edit *own* widgets", "cannot delete widgets", etc). That's a great topic for another question - and one that has probably already been asked/answered well.

Answer (score 10):

Your definition of "secure" is vague. You seem less interested in preventing data from being intercepted, and more interested in keeping people from submitting custom requests to your server. That isn't security, that is just good application design - your program shouldn't accept requests which cause the internal state to break.There is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent people from submitting whatever data they want to. The solution is to validate the data they're submitting server-side, not to try to prevent them from submitting the data client-side, which will always fail.

> I switched to POST

You shouldn't bother; that has nothing to do with security. Use whichever HTTP verb is appropriate for the request. Are you querying information? Use a get request. Are you updating/inserting/deleting information? Use post.

> say someone wants to look up someones information on my SQL server they'd just need to key in right information to my .php file associated

You should be authenticating all requests to make sure they have access to the data they're querying. SSL will help you perform the authentication securely.

> when my website is loaded i have a 80 char hex key generated and saved in the session, and when im sending the ajax call i am also sending the challenge key

This isn't going to help. The entire premise of your question seems to be that the user has Firebug or a similar HTTP debugging tool installed. If they do, your session key is rendered useless.

Comment: maybe you could help clearify something for me, how could my data be intercepted, and if they have firebug, they can just look at my session data? i thought that was saved server side and couldnt be viewed.

Comment: data can be intercepted via packet sniffing on the local network

Comment: wouldnt it be very difficult to get something onto the local network?

Comment: @tye You are correct, session data is stored server-side. The problem is you're sending the 80 character key to the client; it doesn't matter whether they can read the version stored in the session, you're sending the same thing to them in plain text.

Comment: yeah i understand that, which is why i was concerned, but now i changed it so that once its used in the ajax php file it changes it to another random number which is all done on server side without sending it back to client. It wouldnt be sent to the client again until the ajax request is sent again. Does this make sense and should this work?

Comment: @tye No, it shouldn't work. You cannot keep secrets in client-side code; it is trivially easy to watch the data being transfered. You're still layering on this silly "security" when you should be focusing on making your server-side script more robust. There should be no request that somebody can submit to your program which will break it.

Comment: i absolutely agree and i plan to make some changes to make it not possible to break my program. However im still not sure why what i was purposing would not work though. Maybe i wasnt being clear enough or maybe im just retarded. in the php file i would setting the session challenge key to something else, so once that is done i dont see how that new information would get passed back to the client, which it would not be passed back to the client until the ajax request is sent.

Comment: @tye What's the purpose of the key, if it's not passed back to the client? You keep saying it won't be passed back until the request is sent; you can inspect the response to an AJAX request just as easily as you can inspect the request itself.

Comment: well it gets passed when calling the ajax request but the first line in the php file that ajax request pulls is going to check and challenge key and change it so its changed and that new changed one isnt getting passed back to the client until it would come back here during a new ajax reuest, sorry if this has been unclear, im not trying to sound retarded and i understand this is pointless but now im just curious.

Comment: So on request **A**, you submit the key, and it cycles to some new random value which is stored server-side. You're saying you won't pass that value back to the user until request **B**. How is the user supposed to even make request **B** in the first place, if they don't have the key yet? If you're requiring the user to submit some key, you *must* send them that key before they make the request.

Comment: well the key is stored in the session data right, so when the javascript goes to make another ajax request the data being sent is something like "type=foo&name=bar&challenge=<?php echo $_SESSION['challenge']; ?>" and then the first couple of lines in the ajax php that was called are like if $_POST['challenge'] == $_SESSION['challenge'] { $_SESSION['challenge] = newkey;} does that make more sense, again sorry this is tough to explain myself without some code i guess.

Comment: @tye That works if you're only ever going to allow one AJAX request per full page request. What if you want to make a second AJAX request? The key won't match.

Comment: since ive updated the session['challenge'] shouldnt that ajax function send the new updated one and match it against the again updated session key. So shouldnt allow as many requests as i want by that page?

Comment: @tye Not unless you send the new key back as a response to the AJAX request and update all the links on the page with it, or refresh the whole page. The page's links won't magically update themselves; `<?php  echo $_SESSION['challenge'] ?>` is only evaluated once when the page is requested. Changing the value server-side won't affect the code that has already been rendered and sent to the browser.

Comment: @tye Look, computer science is an experimental science. The best thing for you is to try it. I am telling you this will not work, but don't take my word for it, try to prove me wrong.

Comment: forsure, well thank you very much man i really appreciate your help, sorry for eating up a good portion of your day. thanks again. EDIT: actually can i clearify one more thing with you?

Comment: i just wanted to check EDIT im going to post this code as an answer done below, as i understand this should send the updated session key as many times as it needs to send right?

Answer (score 0):

```
function mysqlRequest(type,server,name,value,sync){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
        url: 'sql.php',
        data: "server=s"+server+"&type="+type+"&name="+name+"&value="+value+"&challenge=<?php echo $_SESSION['challenge']; ?>",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: sync,
        success: function(data){
            },
        complete: function(){}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Inspect the page with firebug, and you'll find the value after `"&challenge=` never changes, no matter how many times you change the value of `$_SESSION['challenge']` server-side. You must *manually* update the value based on the result of the AJAX request. It does not happen automatically. This implies that you must send the new key back in response to the AJAX request every time, which defeats the purpose of the key.

Comment: As an aside, are you passing SQL queries to the server via the `value` parameter? This is a terrible, awful, unforgivably bad idea. Anybody can write whatever SQL query they want, and send it. This is the fundamental misunderstanding here - the solution isn't to "secure" the sending of SQL queries to the server; the solution is to *never* send SQL queries.

Comment: yeah those are the changes i was planning on making lol. and ok thank you for information regarding the fact that that code will not send the updated session variable. So you dont think i should use ajax for sql purposes. the whole basis on this game i was making was to eliminate the need for page refreshs. Its going to an MMO style RTS.

Comment: You should use AJAX, but you should also be building your SQL statements server-side. For example: Instead of passing the query SELECT * FROM UNITS WHERE ID = 3` in the query string, you should use a URL like `mysite.com/units.php?id=3`. The whole point is to prevent people from altering your query to insert things like `DELETE` statements.

Comment: now on that subject is acceptable to send information for WHERE = (var) statements to sql queries, as long as they are injection proofed. for any of my ajax request i usually send some of the info for query nothing that the user could select what data to match but what values to match. that is acceptable correct?

Comment: @tye You cannot be too wary of incoming data. I would not accept even a where clause. It's going to be very difficult to scrub SQL injections out of a string which is, by design, is supposed to contain SQL.

Comment: ok that answers my next question too. just wanted to check that, i just dont want someone to be able to use these .php files to select what data is being echo'd, so values good, data table coloumn names no good right?

Comment: so you feel protecting who or what is acessing these files doesnt matters, just matters what is being done inside them right? i just figured it was common practice to secure whats calling these files. This is my first ajax program so i really have no idea whats common practice and whats not.

Comment: You cannot do anything to secure who/what is making requests to your webserver. That isn't how the Internet works.

Comment: ok i gotcha, thanks again dude. i do really appreciate this. Now when you were confused when i said securing my ajax, what kind of security should i be looking into, you were talking about data interception?

Comment: If you're transferring sensitive data like passwords, you should be using SSL.